# Most efficient way to upgrade postgresql 9.0.1 to latest minor version

Tags: postgresql

What is the most efficient way to upgrade postgresql to the latest minor version when I'm running an operating system (Fedora Core 10) that's too old to be supported by official RPM releases?

I have successfully compiled PostgreSQL, but after searching the Internet I can't figure out how to obtain an accurate spec file so I can build a new RPM.

I would like to update *only* the binaries that have changed between 9.0.1 and 9.0.18.

Is there somewhere I can find this information?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Sandra. This is a Professional Q & A site. Please visit [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Fedora core *10*? Gah.

I suggest grabbing the http://yum.postgresql.org/ 9.0.18 SRPM and doing an `rpmbuild --rebuild`. You shouldn't need to make any changes to it.

The SRPM you'll want is the RHEL 6 one, since PGDG no longer does Fedora releases for outdated PostgreSQL versions. It's here:

```
http://yum.postgresql.org/srpms/9.0/redhat/rhel-6Server-x86_64/postgresql90-9.0.18-1PGDG.rhel6.src.rpm
```

so try:

```
sudo yum install rpmdevtools rpmbuild yum-utils
sudo yum-builddep postgresql90-9.0.18-1PGDG.rhel6.src.rpm
rpmbuild --rebuild postgresql90-9.0.18-1PGDG.rhel6.src.rpm
```

If that fails, you can unpack the srpm:

```
# do NOT use sudo:
rpm -i postgresql90-9.0.18-1PGDG.rhel6.src.rpm
```

then edit the specfile in `~/rpmbuild/SPECS/` to fix any problems and:

```
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/postgresql-9.0.spec
```

As for *only the binaries that have changed* - that's a no-go. Just install the RPM. There is absolutely no point trying to selectively update, you'll just increase the chance of making mistakes. If a binary hasn't changed, then there's no reason not to install the new one.

Comment: Hi, how do I get around the GPG key without using rpm --import?

Comment: "get around the gpg key". I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I'm unable to open the rpm. Warning: rpmts_HdrsFrom Fdno: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 442df0f8.  After some investigation is looks like I am missing the Centos GPG key.  Instructions from other sites are to do an rpm --import of the key itself directly to the Linux box I am working on.  My work policy prohibits Internet access via Linux.

Comment: No, that's only a warning. But if your work policy is that limiting you're going to have plenty of problems getting rpm dev tools (rpmbuild etc) and are probably wasting your time. I can't really offer any more help at this time, I'm not able to offer a detailed step by step Q&A.. If you're still stuck I suggest posting a follow up on serverfault and linking back to this question for context. If you do post a follow up please comment here to add a link to it.

Comment: @SandraSmith Though - you can `rpm --import ` a local file, it doesnt have to be a url. So you can work around the policy with a usb key. (These policies are incredibly stupid. They lead to obsolete systems full of long-fixed bugs and security vulnerabilities being left to moulder until its suddenly critically urgent to upgrade. And they encourage workarounds like what you are having to do that are just crazy in comparison to running an up to date supported system in the first place. Not to mention circumventing the distro's signing security.)